# Unable to access workspace on Jenkins Master after build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, kubernetes

I am running a Kubernetes cloud on which I am hosting Jenkins Master CI instances. My JM launches a builder Pod inside the cloud and kills that Pod after build is done (nothing unusual here). I am copying back the workspace on the master with the 'copy-to-slave' plugin. The problem is, I am not able to access my workspace after the build is done, even though the workspace sits on Jenkins Master (I can exec into the JM pod and I can see the workspace under `$JENKINS_HOME/workspace/<job_name>`. Is there any workaround regarding this? How can I access my workspace AFTER the build is done?

Comment: Just wanted to add an existing ticket

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-40805

Answer (score 0):

You need to run specific job at least once on the master. Don't know why such strange behavior, but after one run on master you will be able to see workspace